# how to deal in conda-forge with universal wheels but dependencies which are not universal

Tags: conda

I want to create a recipe for https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python in conda-forge.

In setup.cfg:

```
   [bdist_wheel]
   universal = 1
```

But it has a dependency rsa:

> conda search -c conda-forge rsa
>
> rsa                          3.4.2 py27_0  conda-forge
> 3.4.2                    py34_0  conda-forge
> 3.4.2                    py35_0  conda-forge
> 3.4.2                    py36_0  conda-forge

How can i deal with it?
Can i put the line

> noarch: python

or will it be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `noarch: python` package for any pure Python package which has identical requirements on all platforms and Python versions.  This means that the recipe cannot make use of preprocess-selectors.

The fact that the dependencies are not pure Python has no bearing on the status of the package.

The conda documentation section on [Architecture independent packages](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#architecture-independent-packages) has more details no `noarch: python` packages.